# Webpack cannot identify my JSX syntax inside my js file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

When i try to bundle my modules with webpack, it cannot identify the `JSX` syntax inside my `index.js` file and gives the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 29:3
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (29:3)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|               const searchTerm = _.debounce(term =>     {this.searchTerm(term)}, 300);
|               return (
>                       <div>
|                               <SearchBar onInputChange= {searchTerm}/>
|                               <div className="row">
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.js     main[1]
```

This is my webpack config:

```
const Path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./src/index.js'],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },


 module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        include: Path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
           options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-react",  "@babel/preset-env"]
          } 
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,  
        use: [ 'css-loader' ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './',
    watchOptions: {
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
      poll: 1000
    }
  }
};
```

I have added the babel presets for react namely @babel/preset-react. I have also added the babel-loader but still it cannot identify the JSX syntax.

Comment: Try `"presets": ["react", "env"],`

Comment: Tried it, didn't work @RomanMaksimov

Comment: show your `package.json` please

Comment: https://github.com/kryptokinght/react-youtube-clone/blob/master/package.json @RomanMaksimov

Comment: You may try to add `babel-preset-react-app` preset (`nom i babel-preset-react-app` or `yarn add babel-preset-react-app`) and use `"presets": ["react-app"]`. Also it's better to dedicate the `babel` options into a `.babelrc` file in the root of the app

Comment: what version of dependencies are you using?

Comment: @ickyrr should i install babel-loader, @babel/preset-env, @babel/preset-react as devDependecies or just normal dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cloned your repo and found a bunch of conflicts on your code setup.

1. Some of your packages are not aligned with the latest versions of your `@babel/core` package. If you are going to use the latest version of babel, might as well use the latest presets.

`

```
devDependencies: {
  @babel/cli: ^7.0.0,
  @babel/core: ^7.0.0,
  @babel/preset-env: ^7.0.0,
  @babel/preset-react: ^7.0.0,
  babel-loader: ^8.0.0"
}
```

`

and I removed `babel-preset-env` and `babel-preset-react` (the old versions) on your `dependencies`.

2. Pick one `babel` configuration. It's either on your `package.json` or on `.babelrc`. I suggest you stick with the `.babelrc` file. And changed the values of the `presets` property.

   ```
   `"presets": ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"],`
   ```
3. On your `webpack.config.js` you don't need to do `include: include: Path.resolve(__dirname, './src')`. You can also remove this line:

   ```
   `presets: ["react", "env"]`
   ```

and BTW, on your `package.json`,

`"scripts": {
-    "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
+    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
     ...`

when you run `npm start` your project will look into a locally installed `webpack-dev-server` and use the global one if it does not find the local package.

Hope this helps. :)